# How to deactivate all when saving canvas as image?

Tags: fabricjs

I have a fabricjs canvas with a button to add text to the said canvas and another to save the canvas as an image on my computer. When I have an object selected though when I save, the controls are visible. How can I deactivate the controls when I choose to save the canvas as an image, with an object selected- so that the controls don't persist through to the generated PNG [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/code4ever/0xu3jrL0/)?

[image]

I've tried adding `canvas.deactivateAll();` to different parts of the save function, but it hasn't worked.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', {
  preserveObjectStacking: true,
  lockUniScaling: true,
  centeredScaling: true
});
canvas.setHeight(412);
canvas.setWidth(637);

// Add Text, Enter Editing Mode and Select All
$('#text').on('click', addtext);

function addtext() {
  var text = new fabric.IText('New text');
  canvas.add(text);
  canvas.setActiveObject(text);
  text.enterEditing();
  text.selectAll();
  canvas.renderAll();
}

// Save as image
function download(url, name) {
  $("<a>")
    .attr({
      href: url,
      download: name
    })[0]
    .click();
}

function save() {
  canvas.deactivateAll().renderAll();
  var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
  var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
  var name = 'image';
  download(dataURL, name + ".png");
}
$("#save").click(save);
```

```css
body {
  padding: 10px;
}

canvas {
  border: 1px solid #dddd;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.22/fabric.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<button id="text">
Text
</button>

<button id="save">
Save
</button>

<canvas id='c'></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit 2021 :**

FabricJS doesn't support deactivateAll() anymore and is replaced by discardActiveObject()

So the line

```
canvas.deactivateAll().renderAll();
```

would be

```
canvas.discardActiveObject().renderAll();
```

---

You were very close. Please change canvas variable name inside **save** function to some different name as long as you are using canvas for fabricjs canvas (it just for avoiding confusion).
Update youe **save()** function :

```
function save() {
  canvas.deactivateAll().renderAll();
  var c = document.getElementById('c');
  var dataURL = c.toDataURL();
  var name = 'image';
  download(dataURL, name + ".png");
}
```

You forgot to render canvas after deactivating your object.

Comment: That makes sense. Cheers!